# How do I fix the "wrong number of fields" with the missing commas in CSV file in Go?

Tags: csv, go, foreach

For my CSV files, every row has the same numbers of columns, except for the last row, which was only one column. So, when I read the file data with "foreach" for getting total number of rows, I get the error that it has the wrong number of fields. How do I fix this error without deleting the last row? The code and CSV file are shown below.

```golang
openfile, err := os.Open(filepath)
checkError("Error in reading the file\n", err)

fmt.Println("Already open filepath :", filepath)

//read the data of file
filedata, err := csv.NewReader(openfile).ReadAll()
checkError("Error in reading the file\n", err)

leg := len(filedata)

fmt.Println("total no of rows:", leg)

close := make([]string, leg)
date := make([]string, leg)
open := make([]string, leg)
high := make([]string, leg)
low := make([]string, leg)
adjustclose := make([]string, leg)
volume := make([]string, leg)

for e, value := range filedata {
    date[e] = value[0]
    open[e] = value[1]
    high[e] = value[2]
    low[e] = value[3]
    close[e] = value[4]
    adjustclose[e] = value[5]
    volume[e] = value[6]
}
```

```
2020-03-24,21,21,21,21,21,5
2020-04-06,20.8,20.8,20.8,20.8,20.8,19
2020-04-07,20.4,20.4,20.4,20.4,20.4,5
2020-04-09,20.4,20.4,20.4,20.4,20.4,10
292
```

Comment: See `go doc encoding/csv.Reader.FieldsPerRecord`. Allways, literally **allways** read the full documentation of any package you use. In the case you read the documentation but could make sense of it: Use -1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Disable record length test in the CSV reader by setting [FieldsPerRecord](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv#Reader.FieldsPerRecord) to a negative value.

```
csvr := csv.NewReader(openfile)
csvr.FieldsPerRecord = -1
filedata, err := csvr.ReadAll()
```

Test the record length in the application code:

```
for e, value := range filedata {
    if len(value) < 7 {
        continue  // skip short records
    }
    ...
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XxuXWzQw4n_4).

Comment: oh okay,thank you, it is work, but how do i store all the data into array ? i must create a slices or array right? but without the length of the filedata, how do i do it ?

Comment: @user12952781 Append values to the slices as you go. The example linked from the answer shows how to do this.